# Element LinearLayout Not Allowed Here

Tags: java, xml

I'm getting the error Element LinearLayout is not allowed here in my AndroidManifest.xml file.
I've tried restarting Android studio, but that hasn't had any effect.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Map"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></meta-data>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_lat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_lng"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Why am I getting this warning?

Comment: I'm no Android expert  but I can imagine that you can't just put a UI element inside `application`. You probably want it inside the `activity`. Or maybe you can't put UI definitions in the `manifest` at all? There's probably other xml files for that.

Comment: Word of advice, remove the API key for your google maps . Or at least mask the actual key. Now anyone reaching this page can take and use your API key.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define layout information in your Manifest. The Manifest is meant to describe the application, like which permissions the app uses and which activities reside in your app.

What you're most likely want to do, is open you `activity_main.xml` and Add your layout to that.

Please refer to [layout guide](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/declaring-layout) from the Android Developers documentation on how to get started.

Also for more information on what the Manifest is meant for, refer to the [Manifest Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro).

What you'll want to do to get started, is split the xml in the the appropriate files:

`androidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Map"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></meta-data>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_lat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_lng"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```